# How to mock next-auth v5 when using jest in a nextjs app

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am working on a nextjs project using next v14 and just updated to using next-auth v5. Authentication works fine but i am trying to test the login functionality using jest and i cannot be able to mock next-auth.
Here is my `./auth.ts` file

```html
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

import authConfig from '@/auth.config';
import { User } from '@/types/user';

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {

      return token;
    },
  },
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
  ...authConfig,
});
```

I have created a separate `./auth.config.ts` file with the following contents

```html
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';

import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // validate credentials here and call my endpoint to fetch this user's information
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

I have also created a separate login handler as a server action to call the `signIn` function exported from my `./auth.ts` file. Here is a snippet

```html
import { AuthError } from 'next-auth';

export async function loginUser(formData: z.infer<typeof loginDataSchema>) {
  const validatedFields = loginDataSchema.safeParse(formData);

  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return { error: 'Invalid fields' };
  }

  const { username, password } = validatedFields.data;

  try {
    await signIn('credentials', {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      redirectTo: '/profile,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      return {
        error: "Auth failed",
      };
    }

    throw error;
  }
}
```

My login form is pretty straightforward calling the `loginUser` function above.

I would like to test the form's functionality specifically being able to submit the form and return a success message, however i keep getting the below error in my terminal as the tests run

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'next-auth' from 'auth.ts'

Require stack:
  auth.ts
  src/application/auth-actions.ts
```

Trying this in my login form test component

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { fireEvent, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
import LoginForm from './login-form';

global.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;

global.fetch = jest.fn();

jest.mock('next-auth');

/// some test suites here
```

also fails with this error in my terminal
[image]

next-auth version in my `package.json`

```
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and enabling Jest's ESM support solved the missing module error.

It appears that @auth/core that Next-Auth v5 is built around is only published as an ESM module.

This issue in the next-auth repo helped solved it for me.
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6822

Answer (score 0):

Check out this v4 implementation, you can easily borrow it.

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Header from '../../components/layout/Header'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import {useSession} from "next-auth/react";
jest.mock("next-auth/react");


describe("Header Component", () => {

  it('Show Log Out when has session',
    async () => {
      const mockSession = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 86400).toISOString(),
        user: { username: "admin" }
      };
      (useSession as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce([mockSession, 'authenticated']);
      // @ts-ignore
      // useSession.mockReturnValue([mockSession, 'authenticated']);
      render(<Header/>);
      expect(screen.getByText("LOG OUT")).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})
```

Example from a comment in this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/775#issuecomment-1067494503

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**